# Processing how to translate mouse coordinates

Tags: processing

I am making a 2d plat former esc game and I have my game translate my characters x and y cords so my character is always in the middle of the screen, it seems however that mouseX and mouseY  do not translate... how would I convert the mouseX and mouseY cords?

here is my translation code

```
 void draw() {
  background(100);
  if (updateBlocks == true) {
    updateBlocks();
  }

  pushMatrix();
  translate(-player.location.x + 320, -player.location.y + 320);
  mx = mouseX -player.location.x + 320;
  my = mouseY -player.location.y + 320;
  for(int a = 0; a < mapWidth; a ++) {
   for(int b  = 0; b < mapHeight; b ++) {
    if(mx >= 16 * a && mx <= 16 * a + 16 && my >= 16 * b && my <= 16 * b + 16) {
     map[a][b] = 1;
     updateBlocks();
     break;
    }
   } 
  }
  for (int a = validBlocks.size()-1; a >= 0; a --) {
    PVector validBlock = validBlocks.get(a);
    rect(validBlock.x, validBlock.y, 16, 16);
  }
  player.update();
  player.display();
  popMatrix();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `mouseX and mouseY do not translate'. What are you trying to do exactly? In other words, what *should* happen?

Comment: translate makes the programs 0,0 cords where u specify...but it seems mouseX and mouseY are not affected by it..soo like if i say do translate(width/2,height/2) that means the programs 0,0 cords are in the middle of my window so. if anything is on the farther left of the window its x position is less then 0.. but mouseX would still be  positive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, mouseX and mouseY are in terms of your window, regardless of your transformation matrix (translate, rotate, etc). (0, 0) is at the top-left corner no matter what's going on in your screen.

You have to translate that point yourself. In your case, some basic subtraction will do.

Comment: what would that subtraction be EDIT nvm got it ty for all the help :D